# Cypress basic authentication click cancel [Still Open ]

Tags: authentication, cypress, basic-authentication

how can I dismiss? Any ideas?

I tried some codes/solutions that I found on the internet.
[image]

```
cy.visit("/", {
  auth: {
    username: '...',
    password: '...'
  }
});
```

```
cy.visit('https://username:password@ems.layernote.com')
```

I tried to use similar codes as I write at the top.

Comment: What all did you tried. Please add them in the question.

Comment: added one example code, thank you to warning me.

Answer (score 0):

How about you try this:

```js
cy.visit('https://username:password@ems.layernote.com')
```

Comment: No didn't work, thank you for the advice.